# NRVO with and without default copy constructor

Tags: c++, nrvo

I make a demo code like below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    Test(const Test&);
};
Test::Test(const Test& rhs) {
    cout << "do copy constructor function" << endl;
}
Test::Test()
{
    cout << "do constructor function" << endl;
}
Test::~Test() {
    cout << "do deconstructor function" << endl;
}
Test fun1() {
    Test tmp;
    return tmp;    // NRVO
}
int main() {
    Test t1 = fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

I run it under VS2017 release mode, and c++ standard is set to c++17.
The result is as expected, copy constructor has not been run.

But when I comment out the self-defined copy constructor and run it again:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test {
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
};
Test::Test()
{
    cout << "do constructor function" << endl;
}
Test::~Test() {
    cout << "do deconstructor function" << endl;
}
Test fun1() {
    Test tmp;
    return tmp;    // NRVO
}
int main() {
    Test t1 = fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

It turns out NRVO is invalid, because constructor runs once while deconstructor runs twice.
So why would that be?

Comment: For the record (and whatever the syntax check complains): This thing is called "destructor". ;-)

Comment: It works as expected with gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/1M75MsscW

Comment: NRVO is not mandatory, it's all implementation defined.

Comment: Live demo with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/GebnYYoTe. When I added a member variable of a non-trivial type, NRVO was applied: https://godbolt.org/z/xqc9YM3Wa.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat ~~

Comment: Possibly simpler example of the same problem: https://godbolt.org/z/s6Gaf64vx. In the first case, NRVO is applied, while in the second case, it isn't (local variable `x` is constructed and then destructed).